# Hibernate - Entity class having an attribute that is an interface

Tags: java, hibernate, interface, attributes, persist

I've researched this topic a bit and i'm either finding really old posts or questions that are not exactly what i'm trying to achieve.  I have used Hibernate for years now and I'd consider myself well versed in it.  I have used inheritance in my persistence layer before to represent orders with different types of orders as child classes (for a hospital system) to great results.

I am working on a new project which is for a store and i'm faced with an issue that I'm not sure if Hibernate can solve.  Basically I allow the user to construct Bill objects that contain info you'd expect in a bill : customer name, bill number, total amount, taxes, that kind of stuff.  Each Bill object contains a set of OrderedProduct objects which, in turn, contain a Product object and a quantity.  With only this requirement, my project is actually finished and everything works great.

My customer is now asking for an addition which I'm not sure how to tackle.  I am asked to allow the construction of Kit objects which are nothing but a set of Product objects with a price for both to offer discounts on certain things that are often bought together.  Piece of cake, i built a GUI to build and persist these objects but i now have an issue : How do i wire these Kit objects into a Bill?  My OrderedProduct objects are tied to a Product object currently and this model is obviously not compatible with this new requirement.

I can't use inheritance (to my knowledge) because a Kit is basically nothing but a list of Products with ONE reduced price.  If both these classes were to inherit from a common abstract class, how can one contain a set of the other one?

The way I STARTED to build this is with a Billable interface.  The dropdown that allows for product/kit selection uses the below code to populate itself :

```
items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(productService.findAllInInventory());

@Override
public List<Billable> findAllInInventory() 
{
    List<Product> products = findProductsInInventory();
    List<Kit> kits = findKitsInInventory();

    List<Billable> billables = new ArrayList<>();

    billables.addAll(products);
    billables.addAll(kits);

    return billables;
}
```

This allows one dropdown to contain both types of entities while being completely seamless to the user.  I was getting pretty far into adapting the rest of the bill creation GUI with this concept until I realized : You can't have an attribute of an entity class be an interface type (again, to my knowledge).

Sorry for the long explanation and I hope what I'm trying to do is clear.  I can think of some (less than ideal) workarounds for this but if someone has an idea how to design this model I will gladly hear it!

Thanks

Comment: I ended up adding a Kit property to my BilledProduct entity.  The GUI for creating the Bill object will always show an empty field depending on whether was is ordered is a Kit or a Product object but I was able to make the final bill completely transparent to this fact.  Everything actually works nicely now but i had to refine quite a bit of code since it was ALWAYS expecting a Product object before and it is sometimes null now.  Still, I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion is that you cannot have a persisted property of an entity class be an interface type.  If your design ends up requiring such structure, you will (for now) have to re-structure things.